# Differences in UI between Windows Classic and Windows 7/8/etc cutting off controls

Tags: wpf

I do all my UI design in the Windows Classic theme (that looks like old 95/98). A problem I'm running into is that sometimes, because the borders and title area of current Windows themes are larger, it can cause bits of the UI to get cut off on the right side or the bottom.

What can I do besides designing UI with the Windows 7/8/etc themes active to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: Don't use fixed positioning or dimensions.  Use WPF's many types of panels to build a UI that scales gracefully.  Use the different `SizeToContent` modes for your windows when necessary.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Accomplishing the required UI layout in the cases I'm having problems with is pretty much impossible without using fixed dimensions. There are multiple tabs with different heights/widths worth of content, so using SizeToContent makes the window jump all over the place, especially when anyone types in an auto-sizing text field.